# No temperature change during diabatic expansion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, adiabatic

So, checking some exercises from previous exams of where i study at, there is an exercise that goes like this (copying only the relevant stuff):

> A mole of a diatomic ideal gas expands from A to B isotermically, doubling it's volume. Then in keeps expanding adiabatically in an irreversible way from B to C. (then it goes on in order to complete a cycle).
>   Pa = 400kPa, Ta = 800K, Vb=2*Va, Vc=2*Vb, Pc = Pa/4

So, using PV = nRT i got that Va=16.61 l, Pb = 200kPa, Tb = 800K (because it is an isothermal process from A to B), and here comes what i find weird: Tc = 800K
If that was the case, there'd be no work done, no change in internal energy from B to C... am i to think the values given are wrong?

Comment: In adiabatic expansion temperature should decrease, i.e. one must have $T_c<800$K. Re-check your calculation.

Comment: Va = 1660L not 16.61L

Comment: @BhavyaSharma checked, manually and with Wolfram|Alpha, it's 16.61 L.

Comment: @Deep thanks, i thought so. With the given values, i still get that, so i guess the mistake is there.

Comment: That might be reason..But i am pretty sure that during an adiabatic process...the temperature of the system will increase if work in done ON the system and decrease if work is done BY the system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the given numbers and/or description are wrong. The task contains superfluous information which appears to be contradictory. Quick check: $V_c = 2V_b = 4V_a$, but $P_c = \frac{P_a}{4}$, so $P_a \cdot V_a = P_c \cdot V_c$ and $T_c = T_a$ which is the same as $T_b$ due to isothermal expansion $\rm AB$.

So on $\rm BC$ gas internal energy isn't changed and work is performed by the gas, so the system must receive heat from external sources, thus it's not an adiabatic process. You need to exclude one of these to make task consistent:

- $V_c=2V_b$
- $P_c=\frac{P_a}{4}$
- $\rm BC$ is an adiabatic process